# Не правильно рисуется динамический объект в c++

Tags: ооп, c++

Вот [это чудо](http://codepad.org/BrZMHDKh) рисует три танка из примитивов, которые двигаются в одну сторону экрана. Только тогда, когда идёт выполнение вместо нужного движения, область которая двигается становится чёрной , оставляя за собой черный след. Использую Bloodshed Dev C++.

Comment: без отступов даже смотреть нет смысла

Answer (score 1):

У меня альтернативное предложение. Во-первых, сделать класс танк. В него задать координаты какой-либо фиксированной точки танка. И сделать ф-цию, отрисовывающую танк. Во-вторых, никаких перемещений. Попробуйте для начала полностью сбросить сценки нарисовать танк в новом месте. Будет противно мерцать, но для начала сойдет и не должно быть проблем с заливкой.

Т.е. по-простому:

```
 int x, y, color;
 ...
 while(1) // бесконечный цикл, пока пользователь что-нить не сделает
          // условие выхода придумайте сами
 {
     CTank tank1 (x, y, color);
     tank1->Draw(); // Рисуем
     x = x + 10; // Здесь изменяем координату так как нам надо.
                 // Двигаемся вправо на 10 пикселей за итерацию.
 }
```

Если необходимо - можете добавить к классу танка дополнительные параметры: размер гусениц, длину пушки, ориентацию в пространстве (дуло влево, дуло вправо) и пр.

Честно сказать, разбираться в текущем коде нет никакого желания. Ибо мешанина. В частности, в области "магических констант". Комментарии к коду и названия аргументов ф-ций также [доставляют](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82)

Answer (score 0):

size=imagesize(**x1,x1**,x2,y2); зачем 2 раза x1??? Во втором танке тоже самое...

Comment: єто ничего не поменяло , какая то лажа с функциями...не знаю какие запилить